# Postgres partition pruning

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, database-partitioning, partition-problem

I have a large table in Postgres.

The table name is `bigtable` and the columns are:

```
integer    |timestamp   |xxx |xxx |...|xxx
category_id|capture_time|col1|col2|...|colN
```

I have partitioned the table on modulo 10 of category_id and date part of the capture_time column.

The partition tables look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE myschema.bigtable_d000h0(
    CHECK ( category_id%10=0 AND capture_time >= DATE '2012-01-01' AND capture_time < DATE '2012-01-02')
) INHERITS (myschema.bigtable);

CREATE TABLE myschema.bigtable_d000h1(
    CHECK ( category_id%10=1 AND capture_time >= DATE '2012-01-01' AND capture_time < DATE '2012-01-02')
) INHERITS (myschema.bigtable);
```

When I run a query with category_id and capture_time in the where clause, the partitions are not pruned as expected.

```
explain select * from bigtable where capture_time >= '2012-01-01' and  capture_time < '2012-01-02' and category_id=100;

"Result  (cost=0.00..9476.87 rows=1933 width=216)"
"  ->  Append  (cost=0.00..9476.87 rows=1933 width=216)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on bigtable  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=210)"
"              Filter: ((capture_time >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (capture_time < '2012-01-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (category_id = 100))"
"        ->  Seq Scan on bigtable_d000h0 bigtable  (cost=0.00..1921.63 rows=1923 width=216)"
"              Filter: ((capture_time >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (capture_time < '2012-01-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (category_id = 100))"
"        ->  Seq Scan on bigtable_d000h1 bigtable  (cost=0.00..776.93 rows=1 width=218)"
"              Filter: ((capture_time >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (capture_time < '2012-01-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (category_id = 100))"
"        ->  Seq Scan on bigtable_d000h2 bigtable  (cost=0.00..974.47 rows=1 width=216)"
"              Filter: ((capture_time >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (capture_time < '2012-01-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (category_id = 100))"
"        ->  Seq Scan on bigtable_d000h3 bigtable  (cost=0.00..1351.92 rows=1 width=214)"
"              Filter: ((capture_time >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (capture_time < '2012-01-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (category_id = 100))"
"        ->  Seq Scan on bigtable_d000h4 bigtable  (cost=0.00..577.04 rows=1 width=217)"
"              Filter: ((capture_time >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (capture_time < '2012-01-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (category_id = 100))"
"        ->  Seq Scan on bigtable_d000h5 bigtable  (cost=0.00..360.67 rows=1 width=219)"
"              Filter: ((capture_time >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (capture_time < '2012-01-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (category_id = 100))"
"        ->  Seq Scan on bigtable_d000h6 bigtable  (cost=0.00..1778.18 rows=1 width=214)"
"              Filter: ((capture_time >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (capture_time < '2012-01-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (category_id = 100))"
"        ->  Seq Scan on bigtable_d000h7 bigtable  (cost=0.00..315.82 rows=1 width=216)"
"              Filter: ((capture_time >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (capture_time < '2012-01-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (category_id = 100))"
"        ->  Seq Scan on bigtable_d000h8 bigtable  (cost=0.00..372.06 rows=1 width=219)"
"              Filter: ((capture_time >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (capture_time < '2012-01-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (category_id = 100))"
"        ->  Seq Scan on bigtable_d000h9 bigtable  (cost=0.00..1048.16 rows=1 width=215)"
"              Filter: ((capture_time >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (capture_time < '2012-01-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (category_id = 100))"
```

However, if I add the exact modulo criteria (`category_id%10=0`) in the where clause, it works perfectly

```
explain select * from bigtable where capture_time >= '2012-01-01' and  capture_time < '2012-01-02' and category_id=100 and category_id%10=0;

"Result  (cost=0.00..2154.09 rows=11 width=215)"
"  ->  Append  (cost=0.00..2154.09 rows=11 width=215)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on bigtable  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=210)"
"              Filter: ((capture_time >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (capture_time < '2012-01-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (category_id = 100) AND ((category_id % 10) = 0))"
"        ->  Seq Scan on bigtable_d000h0 bigtable  (cost=0.00..2154.09 rows=10 width=216)"
"              Filter: ((capture_time >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (capture_time < '2012-01-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (category_id = 100) AND ((category_id % 10) = 0))"
```

Is there any way to make partition pruning work correctly without having to add the modulo condition in every query?

Comment: Which version are you using? I think there were some improvements to the planner with regards to partitioning in 9.x

Comment: You can make the constraint a bit less verbose: `CHECK (category_id%10=1 AND date_trunc('month', capture_time) = '2012-01-01'::date)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using 9.1

Comment: @Clodoaldo puing based on time is working fine. only the modulo part is not working as expected. BTW, it is more verbose because the data can be partitioned on week or month for date ranges that are not heavily used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who has the same problem:
I have come to the conclusion that the simplest way out is to change the queries to include the modulo condition `category_id%10=0`

Answer (score 4):

Thing is: for the exclusion constraint PostgreSQL [will create an implicit index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION). In your case this index will be a partial one, 'cos you're using an expresion on the column, not just it's value. And it is stated in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-partial.html) (look for the 11-2 Example):

> PostgreSQL does not have a sophisticated theorem prover that can recognize mathematically equivalent expressions that are written in different forms. (Not only is such a general theorem prover extremely difficult to create, it would probably be too slow to be of any real use.) The system can recognize simple inequality implications, for example "x < 1" implies "x < 2"; *otherwise the predicate condition must exactly match part of the query's WHERE condition or the index will not be recognized as usable*. Matching takes place at query planning time, not at run time.

Thus your results — you should have exactly that same expresion that you've used when creating CHECK constraint.

For HASH-based partitioning I prefer 2 approaches:

- add a field that can take a limited set of values (10 in your case), best if such one exists by design;
- specify hash ranges the same way you specify timestamp ranges: MINVALUE <= category_id < MAXVALUE

Also, it is possible to create a 2-level partitioning:

- on the first level you create 10 partitions based on the category_id HASH;
- on the second level you create necessary amount of partitions based on your date ranges.

Although I always try to use only 1 column for partitioning, easier to manage.

Comment: thanks for your inputs. The code that I posted is doing 2 level partitioning using 1 level of inheritance. Performance wise, it runs faster than the actual 2 level inheritance. I know it should be faster the other way (the way you suggested) because there are less tables to check at first level and at the next level only tables inheriting from the qualifying first level tables have to be scanned. But in practice it is slower.

Comment: What slows it down is the partition pruning logic and not actual table scans. In both cases the optimizer prunes the tables correctly but deciding which partitions to prune takes longer in case of 2 level inheritance.

Comment: An interesting thing about 2 level partitioning is that you can query the level one table and now pruning of level two partitions takes less time. I can use this for archiving data in a way that does not hamper performance.